# How to rotate two diffrent X3D scenes at the same time and on the same mouse event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, x3d, x3dom

do i need some java script or jQuery for this ? I'm just asking because i need something like this http://examples.x3dom.org/cadViewer/slimViewerConrod/index.html.
As you can see you can rotate the main object (main scene) with the axes(helper scene) together with the same mouse event. I'm relative new to X3DOM and i just wanted to ask because i have no clue how it works. If it helps, my X3D scenes are :

`<X3D id="x3dElement">
                <Scene id='scene'>

        <Viewpoint id="part7" position=" 0.028793486820279934 0.06097637432245687 -0.009845212995355457" description="camera"></Viewpoint>
            <Group id='alles' children='gr1 gr2 gr3' render='true'>
                <Group id='gr1' children='gr2 gr3' render='true'>
                    <transform translation='0 0 0' rotation='0 0 0 0'>
                            <Inline nameSpaceName="case" mapDEFToID="true" url="case1.x3d"/>
                    </transform>

                    <transform translation='0 0.02 0.031' Rotation='0.86603 0 0 0'>
                    <transform Rotation='0 0 0 0'>
                        <Inline nameSpaceName="switch" mapDEFToID="true" url="switch1.x3d"/>
                        <Inline id="b_sauele" nameSpaceName="inline" mapDEFToID="true" url="inlineSrc/bSauele/bolt1.x3d" onload="init()" ></Inline>

                    </transform>
                    </transform>
                    <transform translation='-0.03 -0.0155 0.024' rotation='0 1 0 1.5708'>
                    <transform rotation='1 0 0 3.1416'>
                            <Inline nameSpaceName="socket" mapDEFToID="true" url="socket2.x3d"/>
                    </transform>
                    </transform>
                    <transform translation='-0.03 -0.0155 -0.024' rotation='1 0 0 3.1416'>
                    <transform rotation='0 1 0 1.5708'>
                            <Inline nameSpaceName="socket" mapDEFToID="true" url="socket2.x3d"/>
                    </transform>
                    </transform>
                    <transform translation='0.03 -0.0155 -0.024' rotation='1 0 0 3.1416'>
                    <transform rotation='0 1 0 1.5708'>
                            <Inline nameSpaceName="socket" mapDEFToID="true" url="socket2.x3d"/>
                    </transform>
                    </transform>
                    <transform translation='0.03 -0.0155 0.024' rotation='1 0 0 3.1416'>
                    <transform rotation='0 1 0 1.5708'>
                            <Inline nameSpaceName="socket" mapDEFToID="true" url="socket2.x3d"/>
                    </transform>
                    </transform>
                    </Group>
                    <Group id='gr2' children='gr3' render='true'>
                        <transform translation='0 -0.018 -0.01988' Rotation='0 0 0 0'>
                                <Inline nameSpaceName="head" mapDEFToID="true" url="head1.x3d"/>
                        </transform>
                            </Group>
                        <Group id='gr3' render='true'>
                                <transform translation='0 -0.05 -0.0275' Rotation='0 0 0 0'>
                                    <Inline nameSpaceName="shaft" mapDEFToID="true" url="shaft2.x3d"/>
                                </transform>
                                <transform translation='0.0129 0.0129 -0.009' Rotation='0 1 0 3.1416'>
                                    <Inline nameSpaceName="bolt" mapDEFToID="true" url="bolt1.x3d"/>

                                </transform>
                                <transform translation='-0.0129 0.0129 0.009' Rotation='0 1 0 3.1416'>
                                    <Inline nameSpaceName="bolt" mapDEFToID="true" url="bolt1.x3d"/>
                                </transform>

                </Group>

            </Group>

                </Scene>
                </x3d>

                 <X3D id='CoordinateAxes' showStat='false' showLog='false'>
            <scene id="helper_scene">
                <viewpoint id="coordinateAxesViewpoint" centerOfRotation='0 0 0' position='0 0 3'></viewpoint>
                <Inline mapDEFToID="true" nameSpaceName="CoordinateAxes" url="data/CoordinateAxes.x3d"></Inline>
            </scene>
        </X3D>'>`

Comment: you just need to route the (same) mouse coordinates (or any other coords) to both the scenes. For example ROUTE Mouse.position TO X3D1.position and ROUTE Mouse.position TO X3D2.position

Comment: Could you tell me how to route mouse coordinates ( which commands should i use) ?

Answer (score 0):

I personally solved it the following way:

```
X3DomAdapter.syncViews = function(firstView, secondView) {


    function sync(firstView, SecondView) {


        var firstViewarea = $('#' + firstView)[0].runtime.canvas.doc._viewarea;
        var secondViewarea = $('#' + SecondView)[0].runtime.canvas.doc._viewarea;

        if (sync.firstViewmatrix === undefined || sync.secondViewmatrix ===
            undefined) {
            sync.firstViewmatrix = firstViewarea.getViewMatrix();
            sync.secondViewmatrix = secondViewarea.getViewMatrix();
            sync.firstChanged = false;
            sync.secondChanged = false;
            return;
        }

        sync.firstChanged = !(firstViewarea.getViewMatrix().equals(sync.firstViewmatrix));
        sync.secondChanged = !(secondViewarea.getViewMatrix().equals(sync.secondViewmatrix));

        if (sync.firstChanged && InputProcessor.active_view === firstView) {
            secondViewarea.animateTo(firstViewarea.getViewMatrix(),
                secondViewarea._scene.getViewpoint(), 0);
            sync.firstViewmatrix = firstViewarea.getViewMatrix();
            sync.secondViewmatrix = secondViewarea.getViewMatrix();
        } else if (sync.secondChanged && InputProcessor.active_view ===
            secondView) {
            firstViewarea.animateTo(secondViewarea.getViewMatrix(),
                firstViewarea._scene.getViewpoint(), 0);
            sync.firstViewmatrix = firstViewarea.getViewMatrix();
            sync.secondViewmatrix = secondViewarea.getViewMatrix();
        }
    }

    return setInterval(function() {
        sync(firstView, secondView);
    }, 50);
};
```

Applied to your example you should be able to call

```
X3DomAdapter.syncViews("scene", "helper_scene");
```

You may want to replace the jQuery calls and pass in DOM nodes directly through the function plus make this a clean class that stores the states. In my use case I just wanted to sync two x3dom-views (splitscreen mode) and forget about it.